# Single schematic split into multiple PCBs in Altium?

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a single schematic that can create multiple PCBs.

I'm aware of the multi-board capability, however, this seems to use multiple schematics to create the individual PCBs which are then brought together as modules.

I have a use case that requires splitting an existing schematic into 2 separate PCBs for production. I wonder if this can be achieved without redoing the circuit diagram.

Comment: You can always cut and paste. Last I looked (version 18, I think) it was not possible, and I mentioned that to the sales folks. If you do the hierarchical schematic with that in mind it may not be a big deal but the interconnections (eg. connectors pinouts) may not be automatically checked (trying to remember it was more than a year ago).

Comment: I have no knowledge of Altium, but I don't think I will be very practical to have one schematic split into multiple PCBs. The output from the schematic to the PCB process is a netlist and a bill of material for assembly. If the schematic should be split into multiple PCBs, you would somehow have to choose which components goes on which PCB and the netlist has to be split as well. From a circuit/system designer point of view I can see that it would be nice to have everything in one schematic, but when things has to be manufactured it would be asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah looks like creating a duplicate schematic as a start point then deleting components to separate will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that they're panelized, just put multiple designs together.  Remember to rename nets so there are no shared connections between them (otherwise you'll get ratsnests and DRCs between areas).

Most proto fabs, when presented with such a design, will opt to create your panel more or less as given. Clearly indicate where board outlines, cut lines, and tabs/scoring can go; they will adapt it to use their standard tabs and etc..

As for separate PCB files from the start, without hacks or copypasta, no, that is not possible.  It is better to copy the project folder and maintain them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Make a hierachical Schematic Projec and a Multiboard Design. All components of one schematic page need to be on the same PCB. [See Altium Doku](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/designing-systems-with-multiple-boards-ad)